# TIme Separator in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I hope everyone reading this is doing well. I am making attendance sheets on Google Sheets that also calculates the salary of the person. It is entirely automated except for one part, the part that calculates salaries.

For that I need to separate the Hours and Minutes worked so that I can calculate the salary accurately based on 60 minutes instead of the first half being in hours and the second from a percentage of 100.

It coverts the hours into days and omits the remaining hours. Please assist. Thank you!

[What it does](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kV76F.png)

[What it should do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cMPW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HOUR()` returns the hour component of a specific time, so it will always return a value between 0 and 23.

In Google Sheets, times are just numbers where 1 indicates 1 day. So a duration of `hh:mm:ss` means `hh/24 + mm/24/60 + ss/24/60/60` which means `hours_in_a_day + minutes_in_a_day + seconds_in_a_day`. (You can see this if you format the cell as "Number")

So, if you want to extract the hours from a duration, you have to multiply it by 24 and take the `INT()`.

```
=INT(B20*24)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I was going crazy for the last 24 hours and absolutely did not think of this. This resolved the issue. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Spreadsheet time values such was elapsed hours are in units of *days*. In your spreadsheet, salary is recorded per *hour*. To multiply the hours by the salary, first convert the salary per hour to salary per day, and then multiply by the elapsed hours, like this:

`=n((B23 * 24) * B20)`

The `n()` wrapper is there just to get the number format right. You can also leave it out and format the formula cell as **Format > Number > Currency**.

See [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/153710/269219) for an explanation of how date and time values work in spreadsheets.